# How to repeat triggering a script in AutoHotkey by holding down a key?

Tags: autohotkey

I am trying to write a script in autohotkey so that, when I hold <kbd>i</kbd> for every one seconds it trigger a specific script for each of the one seconds. for example when I hold this key for 7 seconds something be done 7 times, or when I hold it for 8.3 seconds it to the same thing 8 times. and when I just press that key ( which takes less than one second) it type that letter.

```
 $i:: 
 KeyWait,i,T0.25 
 If (ErrorLevel) 
 {
    Click, 768,192,10
    KeyWait,i 
 }
    Else
    {
        Send, i
    }    
return
```

By running this script it just do the process once when I hold the key more than one seconds and to do it again I should hold the button again. I'm not sure how to achieve my goal. I added `Loop{}` but the result was typing " i " repeatedly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were fairly close:

```
$i::
KeyWait, i, T1
If (ErrorLevel) {
    Loop 10
        Click, 768,192
} else {
    Send, i
}
return
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. but my goal was clicking 10 times for each seconds of holding the key " i ", there isn't ```Click, 768,192,10``` in your code. in fact it just show how many seconds I hold the key but doesn't perform anything.

Comment: Yes, I wasn't sure exactly what you wanted so I gave an example that demonstrated that it did only do the action once for each second. I'll update it.

Comment: I missed the 10 times for each second, I thought it was one click for each second.

Comment: No problem, you were really close.

Comment: Can you please take a look at this question of mine? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66732238/why-keywait-in-autohotkey-cause-two-letters-be-replaced-during-typing