# Why " Keywait " in Autohotkey cause two letters be replaced during typing?

Tags: autohotkey

I have this script:

```
#IfWinActive Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary
$m:: 
KeyWait,m,T0.25 
If (ErrorLevel) 
 {
    Click, 210,563, 10
    sleep,100
    Send, {Down}
    KeyWait,m 
 }
    Else
    {
        Send, m
    }        
return
 $i::
KeyWait, i, T0.25
If (ErrorLevel) {
    Loop 7
        Click, 768,192,3
} else {
    Send, i
}
return
```

But when I type the letters <kbd>m</kbd> and <kbd>i</kbd> fast to type " mi " it types " im " instead. but when I type them slower, no problem occurs. why this happens and How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this quote from the Threads [page](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Threads.htm) is relevant here:

> Although AutoHotkey doesn't actually use multiple threads, it simulates some of that behavior: If a second thread is started -- such as by pressing another hotkey while the previous is still running -- the current thread will be interrupted (temporarily halted) to allow the new thread to become current. If a third thread is started while the second is still running, both the second and first will be in a dormant state, and so on.
>
> When the current thread finishes, the one most recently interrupted
> will be resumed, and so on, until all the threads finally finish.

I believe when you type i after m, in a quick manner while the m keywait is still inside the timeout, it pauses that keywait and runs i's.

As to how to fix this, merely add [Critical](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Critical.htm) in the m hotkey, note this will make it so no other hotkey will run before this one is done, it will however queue things up:

```
#IfWinActive Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary
$m::
Critical
KeyWait,m,T0.25 
If (ErrorLevel) 
{
    Click, 210,563, 10
    sleep,100
    Send, {Down}
    KeyWait,m 
} else {
    Send, m
}        
return

$i::
KeyWait, i, T0.25
If (ErrorLevel) {
    Loop 7
        Click, 768,192,3
} else {
    Send, i
}
return
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. it worked perfectly for "m" and "i" but the problem is: I have about 10 hotkey in my scripts that use ```KeyWait``` (and some of them without it) I have the same typing mistake for other keys. I tried adding ```Critical``` after each key but it didn't work. can you please help me to solve this issue?

Comment: I've not tested it, but you could: remove critical,  replace your KeyWait's with the 'method #3' from https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/RemapJoystick.htm#button. Or have like 5 scripts, with only one hotkey with critical in each. Without knowing your end goal, it's difficult to suggest a complete solution.

Comment: Thank you. the method #3 in the link seems to be for Joystick. by your second recommendation do you mean creating several scripting files and  putting critical at each one? it might be great if it works

Comment: Yes on the multiple scripts. And yes the example is for a joystick, the the idea is to use a timer, instead of KeyWait. You just adapt it.

Comment: Finally I could solve the issues somehow! Thanks again for helping me out on both this question and the previous one ;)

Answer (score 0):

I've find the following code  [here](https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?p=389194#p389194) by the user " Rohwedder " on a forum of autohotkey site.

```
#IfWinActive Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary
~$m::
KeyWait,m,T0.25
If (ErrorLevel)
{
    Click, 210,563, 10
    sleep,100
    Send, {Down}
}
return
~$i::
KeyWait, i, T0.25
If (ErrorLevel)
    Loop 7
        Click, 768,192,3
return
```

It worked perfectly for me but I realized by writing the `keywait` in this way, when I hold for example <kbd>m</kbd> for few seconds unlike  the script on my question it first type an "m" on the search bar, then do the functions I defined for it (clicking and sending down). so my first expression was trying to fix previous code as suggested in other answer by @Josh by using `critical` . but I had some issues with it too!

Finally I used the above code by a little adjustments: I added this

```
   sleep,50
   send,{backspace}
```

below each hotkey (at first lines inside `if`)  so the result is deleting extra letter that is made by holding a key immediately and then it did functions I defined for it instantly.

So the problem is solved !